# How to send "\t" or "tab" within a string into textbox in selenium without using Clipboard or Actions CTRL+C, CTRL+V

Tags: java, selenium, sendkeys

I have a string like this.

```
String inputString="This\tis\ta\tString";
Webelement inputbox=inputBoxXpath;
inputbox.sendKeys(inputString);
```

The problem with code above is that it sends 'This' then \t is considered a keypress TAB which then moves the focus to next element.

To avoid that I am using the Clipboard way and that works flawlessly as long as the app is in focus.

```
//Partial solution
StringSelection selection = new StringSelection(inputString);
Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
clipboard.setContents(selection, selection);
inputbox.click()
send_keys("CTRL+V") // Paste the string in clipboard.
```

This method works however, when the program is running and I copy something else to Clipboard then the inputString gets replaced by the contents of Clipboard.

This also causes issues if I want to run the code on a server VM

I have also tried `Actions` to send the keys however the output is still faulty.

What I am looking for is a way to use native sendKeys('string') where string contains \t and \n, without using CTRL+C and CTRL+V or getCLipboard and setClipboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with javascript. This allow you to set the value directly into the object.

In Java you execute it like this:

```
    @Test
    public void OptionClickTest() throws InterruptedException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "src/test/resources/chromedriver.exe");
        var driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("https://www.google.com");

        var object = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='q']"));
        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].value='this\tis\tmy\ttext'", object);

}
```

It doesn't work on all types of input boxes - but it worked for me on google so it's worth a go:

[image: tabs in a string in google]

Comment: it does what i asked for. this is the answer, just wondering. why the following code don't work. `(JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(command, object);`  where command is defined as `String command = String.format("arguments[0].value=%s", "Test\tString\ Tests");

Comment: You're missing the single-quotes in your string `command`  - try this `String.format("arguments[0].value='%s'", "hello\tWorld");`   -  it's `='%s'`  with the `'` around it :-)

Comment: For future googlers, if you are trying to set `arguments[0].value` to a **multiline** string then you need to use backtick. So something like this. `String.format("arguments[0].value=\`%s\`", "hello\t\nWorld\t\nAnybody\t\noutthere\t\n");`

Answer (score 0):

Replace '\t' in your input String with '\u0009' ([Java Encoding for Unicode Character 'CHARACTER TABULATION'](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0009/index.htm))

Comment: still gets treated like an actual TAB press, so only sends 'This' then moves onto next element.